# Making clip-path work with draggable image

Tags: html, css, draggable, clip-path

I have an element with a custom shape drawn with `clip-path`. When using the html5 `draggable` attribute, the clip-path is ignored on the dragged image. Is there a way to have the clip-path work on the image ? An alternative to using clip-path to easily (no hacky `::before` and `::after` tricks) draw custom shapes working on drag might also be an accepted answer .

([Beware, browser support is limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Compatibilit%C3%A9_des_navigateurs))

```css
#foo {
   padding: 0 1ch;
   clip-path: circle(50%);
   color: white;
   background: indianred;
}
```

```html
<label id="foo" draggable="true">bar</label>
```

To replicate run the snippet, click on bar and drag. Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code it is hard to say what is wrong but here is an example of a working draggable element using clip path. I just modified some code from w3schools so this is not my original work.
https://codepen.io/zenRyoku/pen/EzWmmP

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: plum;
  text-align: center;
  clip-path: circle();
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However I did make another example where items were being dragged into another container and the clip path goes away on drag and comes back on mouseup. Perhaps that replicates your problem? In that case it might be a matter of implementing Javascript as above or making an SVG with the shape you want and using that as the background of a draggable element.
https://codepen.io/zenRyoku/pen/XwMgmM

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#drop {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

#drag1 {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: pink;
  clip-path: circle();
}

#drag2 {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: plum;
  clip-path: circle();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body onload="makeDraggable(evt)">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      <label id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></label>
      <div id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```